# How to configure glassfish 3.1 security file realm using Netbeans 7.1?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to configure a simple file realm in glassfish 3.1 following this [tutorial](http://www.jairrillo.com/blog/2009/08/16/jee-security-how-to-setup-authentication-on-glassfish-and-netbeans/):

I did everything as it says but doesn't work, when I travel to the admin page doesn't I don't see the pop up message asking for credentials.
This is what I did:

**1- Create a file realm:**
[image]

**2- Then I created a user using the manage users button**
[image]

**3-I created a glassfish-web.xml file using the graphic interface instead of the editors**
[image]

**4-Then in the same way I configured the web.xml**
[image]
Sorry if this last image is a bit hard to see, you can zoom.

When I use the URL to travel to /admin.xhtml nothing stops me from viewing the content of the page, this means something is not configured right.
I don't know what am I missing.
Could somebody give me a hand trying to find the reason I cannot make this simple security task work?

**Update**

Here my web.xml source

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allowed</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

and also glassfish-web.xml source

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Basically what I want to do is having 2 types of users. Guests who just browse index.xhtml and they have no credentials at all and the administrators who have their credentials stored in the file and are asked for them when going to admin.xhtml

I don't understand what is missing. Do I need to create special privilege for guest users saying that they can view index.xhtml?

Comment: You can't possibly be using Netbeans 3.1 can you?  Uber antiquated Netbeans 5 came out over 6 years ago.

Comment: @jahroy Hehe... ups i made a mistake in the question title :) Sure i use Netbeans 7.1

Comment: Did you try restarting glassfish and undeploy/deploy your application? If that doesn't help carefully look through the glassfish startup log for any messages related to your realm (it should at least be mentioned if not glassfish isn't picking it up). It might be helpful if you posted the source of web.xml.

Comment: @Eelke I did deploy and undeploy, the only info i see in the console when starting glassfish is this: `INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
I`. I updated the question with the sources.

Comment: Do you see the content of admin.xhtml or do you see something different?  If you see the content of the page you may have already established your credentials as the user 'test'.  Restarting your browser may help you get back to a state where the browser is being used by an unauthenticated user.

Comment: @Eelke Yes i see the content i try closing the browser and opening it again but i never see the message asking for credentials pop up. Maybe i need some other role to be the default role?You know what i mean? Because "administrator" in the only configured role so always is logged in. I don't really understand what is the problem.

Comment: +1 for the link of the tutorial!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your admin.xhtml is a JSF page then because your JSF mapping is /faces/* you are opening it through a URL like http://localhost:8080/[Project/]faces/admin.xhtml. This does not match /admin.xhtml

Replace:

```
<url-pattern>/admin.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

with

```
<url-pattern>/faces/admin.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Yes that was the mistake. 
Thank you very much.